# A template method to take both const and non-const arguments

Tags: c++, templates, constants, c++17

I have a method with the following signature

```
template <typename T>
bool are_equal(T& lhs, T& rhs) { ... }
```

It can only take non const arguments because it uses some STL algorithms on a legacy class which only provides non-const iterator. At the same time the rest of the API is inconsistent in a way that it provides `shared_ptr's` to `T` or to `const T` so I have to do a lot of `are_equal(const_cast<T&>(*lhs_ptr), *rhs_ptr)` for either lhs argument, rhs or both.

Is there a way to have a single method (as opposed to 4 overloaded ones) which would take any combination of `T&` and `const T&` arguments (or `shared_ptr<T>` / `shared_ptr<const T>` and always convert them to `T&` before calling `are_equal`? I've tried playing around with `std::conditional` and `std::remove_const` but couldn't really get anywhere.

Example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/243a98895aa4f6ce

Comment: Since `T` is a template type, `T` can be a const qualified type.  The code will already work with const types: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4af1959915b3a09a

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. Depending on what `...` actually is the function might already work for `shared_ptr` / const types or it might not... to know one would need to see the code

Comment: @NathanOliver: The issue is when the two arguments have different *cv*-qualifications.

Comment: @NathanOliver the comment above is right, the problem is caused by lhs and rhs having different constness.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 here you go: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/243a98895aa4f6ce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is `const`-qualify everything (allowing either kind of argument) and then use `const_cast`:

```
template <typename T>
bool are_equal(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {
  return detail::are_equal
    (const_cast<T&>(lhs),
     const_cast<T&>(rhs));
}
```